# Ajax.ActionLink inside target div to update target div

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor

Scoured a bunch of articles and questions here but can't get to the bottom of this.

I have a page that opens a file manager inside a jqueryUI dialog. This file manager simply displays some thumbnails and a list of sub folders within the main assets folder. The idea is the user clicks a sub folder and gets the thumbs within that folder and a list of sub folders .. I'm sure you get the idea. But, when clicking the folder link the whole page is updated not just the dialog.

In the parent page I am referencing

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the jquery functions to prepare and open the dialog:

```
$("#scopeManagerDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: "File Manager",
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $("#openScopeManager").click(function() {
            $("#scopeManagerDialog").load("@Url.Action("Index", "ScopeManager")",
                function(response, status, xhr) {
                    $("#scopeManagerDialog").dialog("open");
                });
            return false;
        });
```

and the div it loads into:

```
<div id="scopeManagerDialog" title="Scope Manager" style="overflow: hidden">
</div>
```

the controller action that returns the partial

```
public ActionResult Index(string path)
        {
            if (path==null)
            {
                path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["assetRoot"];
            }

            List<AssetVM> assets = ScopeManager.GetAllAssets(Server.MapPath(path));
            List<FolderVM> folders = ScopeManager.GetAllFolders(Server.MapPath(path));
            AssetSetVM model = new AssetSetVM()
                                {
                                    Path = path,
                                    Assets = assets,
                                    Folders = folders
                                };
            return PartialView("ScopeManager", model);
        }
```

and finally the partial itsself. Note that the ActionLink refers to the containing div (I'm wondering if this is the issue .. I hope not and my gut says this should be possible).

```
<div id="scopeManagerContainer">
    <div id="folderList">
        <ul>
            @foreach (FolderVM folder in Model.Folders)
   {
                <li>@Ajax.ActionLink(folder.Name,"Index","ScopeManager",new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "scopeManagerContainer"})</li>
   }
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="fileList">
        @foreach (AssetVM asset in Model.Assets)
  {
            <img src='@Url.Action("GetThumbnail", new { path = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Model.Path, asset.FileName), width = 100, height = 100 })' />
  }
    </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if anything else is required. As I say the first load works. Everything is appearing correctly, just that when I click the folder link it re-renders at the page level instead of updating the contents of the dialog.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error .. I should have been setting the target to scopeManagerDialog not scopeManagerContainer. The question really is a bit pointless now but not sure what the policy is on deleting questions. I'll leave it for now for a mod to decide what to do with it.